# How can I display estimated reading time in blog sidebar of wordpress?

Tags: blogs, wordpress-shortcode

```
    $item = get_post($id);

    $thumb = get_post_meta( $id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
    ?>

        <div class="post-img post-single-img"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image($thumb, ''); ?>
            <div>
                <span class="cat_name"><?= $cat; ?></span>
                <h4><?php echo esc_html(single_post_title()); ?></h4>
                <span calss="time-reading">
                    <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
                    <?= do_shortcode('[rt_reading_time]') ?>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>


 <?php endwhile;
 ?>
```

Here I could add the reading time in single blog page
but I couldn't find blog sidebar to add this short code.